# query em SQL que retorne as vendas mensais de cada produto

Tags: mysql, sql

Considerando um banco de dados mysql ou pgsql, imagine haver uma tabela produto (id, nome, valor) e outra tabela vendas (id, data, produto_id, qtde). Monte uma query em SQL que retorne as vendas mensais de cada produto (mes, produto, qtde, valor total).

Comment: Seja benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! 

Para melhorar sua experiência aqui, fazer a pergunta de forma que possa ser respondida, recomendo ler: [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  [Guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Obrigado!

Comment: olá e bem vindo ao SO Pt Luan, sugiro ler isso_ [Que erro cometi ao formular minha pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-cometi-ao-formular-minha-pergunta)  não vamos ler o seu encioado e resolver o seu problema, ao invés disso, mostre o código que já fez e onde tem dúvida para que possa ter ajuda

Comment: Pesquise por join , group by e functions de data.

Answer (score -2):

Faça um select na tabela VENDAS com join na tabela PRODUTOS, desse jeito:

```
select
p.nome,
SUM(v.qtde)
from vendas v
inner join produtos p on (p.id=v.produto)
where
v.mes=9
```